# Contents page in UIPageViewContainer IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm pretty new to this and have come to a sticking point.
I'm have an ios app that uses UIPageViewController and an array of ViewControllers to create a book style app with the ViewControllers being each page.
I was able to create a menu in the mainViewController (MyParentViewController* that contains the UIPageViewController) which allows me to navigate to a specific page in my book with a nice fancy animation.

This has been put together using typical deployment methods so there's nothing fancy going on.

I decided,however, that it would be nicer if the first page of the book acted like a menu and allowed people to jump to a specific page in the book. This involves requesting to switch pages from the menu page's parent (which seems to be the sticking point).

So when i try to use a method defined in my parent (from the child) like so:

```
MyParentViewController* viewController = (MyParentViewController*)self.parentViewController;
[viewController goToPage:targetPage];
```

It thinks it's a standard UIPageViewController where that method doesn't exist and so I get nowhere.

```
[self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[MyParentViewController class]]
```

Trying this is confirming to me that my parentViewController is of class UIPageViewController and not MyParentViewController.

How do I go about accessing the parent methods to enable this functionality?
Am I going the wrong way about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i made all the controls on the view controller itself, placing a  UIPageViewController on top. This allowed me to control the UIPageViewController with links displayed on the UIViewController.